# Enlarged logo for desktop view, but now extra padding around logo on mobile view

Tags: css

Working on this site: https://redheadedroux.com/
Using Sprinkle Pro Theme

The logo image is automatically designed to size down to 150px in height. I added this code to make it larger:

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
    height: 300px;
}
```

It looks perfect on the desktop view but now when I view the site on a mobile view, I'm left with large padding space between the announcement/hamburger menu and the first widget. I don't want there to be all of that empty space between the logo and everything else.
I've tried adjusting things in the @media areas already within the theme itself, but nothing seems to work. I feel like it's a matter of selecting this height for a different @media area? But I can't seem to get it to work. Any insight?
Thank you

Photo of what it looks like on mobile view:

[image: Mobile view]

Answer (score 0):

Checking your site I can't see any problem at all. Everthing works as You have decided.

If you have the rule:

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
    height: 300px;
}
```

and you are not happy how it looks on mobile, change it with [`media queries`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-image .site-title > a {
    height: 120px;
    }
}
```

Just use the window width when you desire to use the change of height and be sure the rule is placed at the bottom of you css sheet.

Comment: Hi there-
Thank you for your insight. I tried what you suggested, but it didn't change the height for the image on my phone. It stayed the same.
Now, if I take out the 300px code I added, when I look at it on my phone, it's great- no extra padding around the image. But then it's way too small on the desktop view etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue. I ended up applying this specific code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .header-image .site-title > a {
    height: 300px;
    }
}
```

It left the logo sizing alone for any screen size below 600px. But for anything 600px and above, it made the logo height 300px, which is exactly what I wanted. The padding around the logo image on mobile devices is no longer there.